# Delete My Site Status Updates

Tags: 2010, my-site

How can you delete previous status updates within My Sites in SharePoint 2010? There is no delete option when looking through previous updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that is not possible in SharePoint (at least out of the box).

Comment: Whats why nobody answers this for 4 years. because such answer is not an answer :) Ok, I will rephrase my answer